# Using the Object fetch mode with foreach

Tags: php, pdo

i use `$text =$product[0];` and `$time =$product[1];` in my code:

```
<?php
include("cache/phpfastcache.php");
phpFastCache::setup("storage","auto");
$cache = phpFastCache();
$products = $cache->get("product_page");
if($products == null) {
$akhbarkotah1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT text,time FROM small WHERE active='0' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");
$akhbarkotah1->execute();
$products = $akhbarkotah1->fetchAll();
$cache->set("product_page", $products,10);
}
foreach($products as $product){
$text =$product[0];
$time =$product[1];
?>
<a class="lastnews">
<div id="lastnews_title" class="YekanBlack10" style="width:585px;">
<div><?php echo $text; ?></div>
<div class="YekanRed10" style="text-align:left">
<?php echo timeTonow($time); ?>
</div>
<div style="border-bottom:2px solid #7c0000;height:5px;"></div>
</div>
</a>
<?php
}?>
```

i want change to object fetch 
when change variables to

```
foreach($products as $product){
    $text =$product->text;
    $time =$product->time;
```

not work

where is the problem?

Comment: Check if the `fetchAll()` in your DB class return just `mysqli_fetch_array` try to create another function or send a parameter to return the result of `mysqli_fetch_object`

Comment: you should apply some kind of Formatting/Indentation to your code.  your `foreach` is missing it's closing bracket.   you probably want to echo all the HTML inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following:

```
  $products = $akhbarkotah1->fetchAll();
  $cache->set("product_page", $products,10);
}
foreach($products as $product){
  $text =$product[0];
  $time =$product[1];
?>
```

to

```
  $cache->set("product_page", $products,10);
}
foreach($product = $akhbarkotah1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  $text = $product->text;
  $time = $product->time;
?>
```

Comment: not work , because you use foreach without (as $var)
and you remove $product in cache

Comment: @Mohammad I've no idea what `cache` does.

Comment: foreach or while?  - your write foreach without as $var